# Oracle setup estimate

Tags: linux, oracle

I need to set up a new database (Oracle), on a new system. I need to prepare the costing.
Can anyone please suggest what all this will involve. I can think of Oracle licenses, hardware boxes, etc. I've no idea which processor to go for (and how many cores) and how much RAM should be sufficient. Apart from this what else do I need to setup a complete box with Oracle, cluster and SAN as well.

I know the requirement vary from case to case. But in this case the traffic is not be huge.

If someone can give just rough idea and point me somewhere, that will be great.

Comment: A couple of important things are missing: what os, if RAC is used, if yes how many nodes, what other oracle features are planned (like data guard , golden gate...), what monitoring solution will be used. What is the network infrastructure? Has a proof of concept been made? Which client software will be used? does it require a specific oracle version? and so on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start here: [Software Investment Guide](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/sig-070616.pdf).

When you understand what Oracle version you need, 
you should check the HW and SW requirement here: [Oracle Database Online Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage).

Comment: thanks for links, much appreciated. But can you please give a general list (not specific)??

Comment: Hi @adi, the list needs to be specific, otherwise there may be a significant variation in the costs ... I believe the best suggestion here is not to try to estimate the costs quickly: you need to study well the business requirements before buying anything.
Anyway, consider reading the minimal requirements listed in the install guides, they could give you an idea.

Comment: thanks, I am not buying anything. Just that with a general list I can get a draft version done. I am only trying  to understand things for now. If you can provide just a general list, I can work on it to customize it. Anyways this being a lage multinational, things take way too long to get done. For now, all I need is a proposal\estimate.